Implementing n-player Elo rating in pandas dataframe
Sorry if this is a rather complicated question.
I have a pandas dataframe that records the result of races between different players:
Race_ID records different races
Racer_ID records different players
N denotes the number of players in that game
Place denotes the outcome of that game, with 1 being the winner, 2 being the first runner up, etc.
I want to add a new column called Elo_rating to represent the current elo rating of that player using the following algorithm for n-player elo:

If this is the first game for that player, then give them an elo rating of 400:

Date        Race_ID     N   Racer_ID    Place   Elo_rating
1/12/2021   10055116    4   1           3       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   2           2       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   3           1       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   4           4       400
3/5/2022    10055117    3   2           1       
3/5/2022    10055117    3   3           2       
3/5/2022    10055117    3   4           3       
2/12/2022   10055118    5   1           3       
2/12/2022   10055118    5   3           5       
2/12/2022   10055118    5   4           2       
2/12/2022   10055118    5   5           4       400
2/12/2022   10055118    5   6           1       400
1/1/2023    10055119    4   1           1       
1/1/2023    10055119    4   4           3       
1/1/2023    10055119    4   5           4       
1/1/2023    10055119    4   6           2       


Compute the expected rating of player x by the following formula:


where D=400, and if this is the first game for that player, then set E_i = 1/N

After the race result is out, the Score function for player i is given by

S_i = (N - place) / (N(N-1)/2)
So for example, the score for player 1, 2, 3, 4 after the first race (Race_ID = 10055116) are respectively
S_1 = (4-3) / (4(3)/2) = 1/6,
S_2 = (4-2) / (4(3)/2) = 2/6,
S_3 = (4-1) / (4(3)/2) = 3/6,
S_4 = (4-4) / (4(3)/2) = 0/6.

Finally the elo rating update for the next race is given by

E_i <- R_i + 30(S_i - E_i)
So for example the elo rating for the second race (Race_ID = 10055117) is given by
Date        Race_ID     N   Racer_ID    Place   Elo_rating
1/12/2021   10055116    4   1           3       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   2           2       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   3           1       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   4           4       400
3/5/2022    10055117    3   2           1       402.5
3/5/2022    10055117    3   3           2       407.5
3/5/2022    10055117    3   4           3       392.5
2/12/2022   10055118    5   1           3       397.5
2/12/2022   10055118    5   3           5       407.212315853
2/12/2022   10055118    5   4           2       382.859605171
2/12/2022   10055118    5   5           4       400
2/12/2022   10055118    5   6           1       400
1/1/2023    10055119    4   1           1       
1/1/2023    10055119    4   4           3       
1/1/2023    10055119    4   5           4       
1/1/2023    10055119    4   6           2       

And the desired output is given by
Date        Race_ID     N   Racer_ID    Place   Elo_rating
1/12/2021   10055116    4   1           3       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   2           2       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   3           1       400
1/12/2021   10055116    4   4           4       400
3/5/2022    10055117    3   2           1       402.5
3/5/2022    10055117    3   3           2       407.5
3/5/2022    10055117    3   4           3       392.5
2/12/2022   10055118    5   1           3       397.5
2/12/2022   10055118    5   3           5       407.212315853
2/12/2022   10055118    5   4           2       382.859605171
2/12/2022   10055118    5   5           4       400
2/12/2022   10055118    5   6           1       400
1/1/2023    10055119    4   1           1       383.501122
1/1/2023    10055119    4   4           3       372.913004
1/1/2023    10055119    4   5           4       382.8213312
1/1/2023    10055119    4   6           2       391.8213312

I have no idea how I can approach this problem, but I guess we should start by groupby the Racer_ID and then applying .map but I have no idea how to implement it. Thank you so much.

Black text on transparent background (as in your formula) is completely illegible in dark mode... If you must use an image at least make the background white.

Hi, I just updated and make the data as text, thanks.

Thanks. It's much more useful now.

You can try (note, I believe the elo ratings for race 10055119 should be different according to your formula):
# set ELO for first game for player to 400
elos = dict.fromkeys(df["Racer_ID"].unique(), 400)

out = []
for i, (_, g) in enumerate(df.groupby("Race_ID")):
    N = len(g)

    g["Elo_rating"] = df["Racer_ID"].map(elos)

    # update elos:
    tmp = {}
    for racer, place in zip(g["Racer_ID"], g["Place"]):
        if i == 0:
            E = 1 / N
        else:
            E = 0
            for p in g["Racer_ID"]:
                if p == racer:
                    continue
                E += 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((elos[p] - elos[racer]) / 400))
            E /= (N * (N - 1)) / 2

        S = (N - place) / ((N * (N - 1)) / 2)
        tmp[racer] = elos[racer] + 30 * (S - E)

    elos.update(tmp)
    out.append(g)

out = pd.concat(out)
print(out)

Prints:
         Date   Race_ID  N  Racer_ID  Place  Elo_rating
0   1/12/2021  10055116  4         1      3  400.000000
1   1/12/2021  10055116  4         2      2  400.000000
2   1/12/2021  10055116  4         3      1  400.000000
3   1/12/2021  10055116  4         4      4  400.000000
4    3/5/2022  10055117  3         2      1  402.500000
5    3/5/2022  10055117  3         3      2  407.500000
6    3/5/2022  10055117  3         4      3  392.500000
7   2/12/2022  10055118  5         1      3  397.500000
8   2/12/2022  10055118  5         3      5  407.212316
9   2/12/2022  10055118  5         4      2  382.859605
10  2/12/2022  10055118  5         5      4  400.000000
11  2/12/2022  10055118  5         6      1  400.000000
12   1/1/2023  10055119  4         1      1  397.500337
13   1/1/2023  10055119  4         4      3  386.175625
14   1/1/2023  10055119  4         5      4  396.946399
15   1/1/2023  10055119  4         6      2  405.946399


Same thing @Andrej was mentioning in his solution, need to check your rating, I think it should be different from expected output.
Logic

As we don't know when will a player participate in next match, for that we need to create backlog (elo_rating_backlog), when a player participate in next match we will use this as current rating and will update after match rating into backlog.
Need one set variable that store all the previously played players and using set operation we can know from current match playing player who are new and we can assign initial rating of 400.0

Remaining logic is pretty simple I think.
current_match_players = set(group['Racer_ID'])
new_registered_players = set.difference(current_match_players, registered_players)
registered_players.update(set.difference(current_match_players, registered_players))
for new_registered_player in new_registered_players:
    elo_rating_backlog[new_registered_player] = 400.0

Solution
from collections import defaultdict
registered_players = set()
elo_rating_backlog = defaultdict(float)

for name, group in df.groupby(by=['Race_ID']):
    # set inital rating for new registerd players
    race_id = group['Race_ID'].unique().item()
    N = group['N'].unique().item()
    current_match_players = set(group['Racer_ID'])
    new_registered_players = set.difference(current_match_players, registered_players)
    registered_players.update(set.difference(current_match_players, registered_players))
    for new_registered_player in new_registered_players:
        elo_rating_backlog[new_registered_player] = 400.0
    
    # evaluate new ratings
    for racer_id in current_match_players:
        current_racer_data = df[(df['Racer_ID'] == racer_id) & (df['Race_ID'] == race_id)]
        place = current_racer_data['Place'].item()

        S = (N - place) / ((N * (N - 1)) / 2)
        E = 0
        for x_racer_id in current_match_players.difference({racer_id}):
            other_racer_data = group[(group['Racer_ID'] == x_racer_id)]
            E += 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((other_racer_data['Elo_rating'].item() - current_racer_data['Elo_rating'].item()) / 400.0))
        E /= (N * (N - 1)) / 2

        backlog_pop = elo_rating_backlog[racer_id]
        index_ = group[group['Racer_ID'] == racer_id].index.item()
        df.loc[index_, 'Elo_rating'] = backlog_pop
        elo_rating_backlog[racer_id] = backlog_pop + 30.0 * (S - E)

Output
         Date   Race_ID  N  Racer_ID  Place  Elo_rating
0   1/12/2021  10055116  4         1      3  400.000000
1   1/12/2021  10055116  4         2      2  400.000000
2   1/12/2021  10055116  4         3      1  400.000000
3   1/12/2021  10055116  4         4      4  400.000000
4    3/5/2022  10055117  3         2      1  402.500000
5    3/5/2022  10055117  3         3      2  407.500000
6    3/5/2022  10055117  3         4      3  392.500000
7   2/12/2022  10055118  5         1      3  397.500000
8   2/12/2022  10055118  5         3      5  407.212316
9   2/12/2022  10055118  5         4      2  382.859605
10  2/12/2022  10055118  5         5      4  400.000000
11  2/12/2022  10055118  5         6      1  400.000000
12   1/1/2023  10055119  4         1      1  397.500028
13   1/1/2023  10055119  4         4      3  386.183052
14   1/1/2023  10055119  4         5      4  396.946092
15   1/1/2023  10055119  4         6      2  405.946092
...

